# curl remote login erro

Tags: php, ajax, curl

Curl code:

```
$username = $_POST["email"];

$password = $_POST["password"];

$headers= array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'); 

$url="http://localhost/hrm_1.7/source/admin/login"; 

$data = array('email'=>$username,'password'=>$password);

$postinfo = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postinfo);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/hrm_1.7/source/admin/dashboard");

$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: " http://localhost/hrm_1.7/source/admin/login ",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#login-form').serialize()

 }).done( function( response ) {
        if(response.status == "success")
        {
            window.location.href= "http://localhost/hrm_1.7/source/admin/dashboard";
        }

 });
```

AJAX code is working fine and on success it logins and redirect to dashboard.But i want to do using curl.What is wrong with my curl code?

Comment: is there any $_POST reciver type methods in admin/dashboard?

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty that i dont know my ajax code is working and i need to know what is wrong with my curl code.

Answer (score 0):

U use two times CURLOPT_URL and the last one is used.

So you are sending to http://localhost/hrm_1.7/source/admin/dashboard

Comment: Thats because I have to redirect to that URL...same like in Ajax request I redirect after success response...at the end I want to redirect only

Comment: actually I want remote login and this crm is laravel based.I want request to be done to subdomain.So I put header(allow origin..) in crm of laravel but On using above Ajax code I got redirected to logout page but my data is posted without any cross domain error. please help me.